# Will including these javascript files in the header eliminate Etag errors, and other SEO errors from YSlow?

Tags: asp.net, performance, yslow

I have been working on performance lately, and recently ran a YSlow test on my company's asp.net website.  I have already set up an IIS7 rule to set expiration dates to 30 days.  After researching, I think Yahoo suggests you add tags like this to your head section:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/get/get-min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"> 
</script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/imageloader/imageloader-min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/cookie/cookie-min.js"></script>
```

If you see this link, [Yahoo's recommendations on how to improve SEO](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=), it seems as if yahoo suggests putting these .js files in your header.

Are these javascript files from yahoo something you should include in your head section?  Or are they just unnecessary external .js files that will slow your site down?  I just don't understand yahoo's logic behind this.  Any guidance to clear this up would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Those files are YUI version 2 (deprecated) YUI3 is the latest, if your website is not using any of these components then you're ok to remove them from HEAD section. If your website is indeed using those YUI2 files then you can get the combined version of all the links above in order to have only 1 script tag and move it to the bottom of your page next to .